# Which Adventures have a Sun Blade?

Tags: magic-items, dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures

This is going to be a question to all the old-bees. Which D&D adventures (any edition) have a *sun blade* as a magic item? I thought *Temple of the Frog* did, but cannot find it in the module.

Answer (score 15):

- I10 *Ravenloft II: The House on Gryphon Hill*, though it imposes a penalty if removed
- *Book of Lairs* (Dragonlance Lairs), in the adventure *Stahnk*
- FOR5 *Elves of Evermeet*, carried by Lady [Ahskahala Durothil](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ahskahala_Durothil)
- FRE2 *Tantras*, carried by the avatar of Torm
- *The Ruins of Myth Drannor*, in the adventure *What We Face in Dreams*
- *The Ruins of Undermountain* (DM's choice)
- *Night Below*, in a chest
- HHQ5 *Fighter's Challenge II*, in an armory
- *Anauroch: The Empire of Shade*, where one appears in Askilion's Tower
- The Dungeon #17 adventure *Out of the Ashes*
- The Dungeon #51 adventure *Ailamere's Lair*
- The Dungeon #54 adventure *Dark Thane Macbeth*, where it is carried by Macduff
- The Dungeon #71 adventure *Dreadful Vestiges*
- The Dungeon #134 adventure *Into the Wormcrawl Fissure*, where it appears in Dragotha's hoard
- The Dungeon #145 adventure *City of Broken Idols*
- The Polyhedron #42 adventure *The Charleston Academy*, where the character Anastasia carries one

Comment: How did you get this list?

Answer (score 12):

### In 5th Edition

In addition to [Quadratic Wizard's exhaustive list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201962/75095) for older editions, here are adventures from 5th edition that include a [*sun blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4774-sun-blade):

- *Candlekeep Mysteries*
- *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*
- *Journey through the Radiant Citadel*, in "Trench of Love Lost"
- *Out of the Abyss* ([*Dawnbringer*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5533-dawnbringer) – not technically a *Sun Blade*, but it "has all the properties of a *sun blade*"
- *Curse of Strahd* (the [*Sunsword*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5532-sunsword) – not technically a *Sun Blade*, but it "has all the properties of a *sun blade*")